# scan uri of multiple files?

Tags: android, uri

public void walkdir(File dir) {
        String pdfPattern = ".png";

```
    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)) {

                    scanFile(listFile);**Not working**

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so how can i scan the directories for images

this is media scanner---

```
 private void scanFile(String path) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{path}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.wtf("ff", "ff");
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to scan directories for a specific file extension such as .png

You could try something like this.

```
    File dirs = new File(path);
    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
   @Override
    public boolean hasFiles(File file) {
    return file.getAbsolutePath().matches(".*\\.png");
    }
    };
    File[] images = dirs.listFiles(filter);
```

For more informatio check : [FileFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Scan for images in a folder like this

```
ArrayList<String> myFiles=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> getImages(String Foldername){    

File vaultt = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"+ Foldername+"/");
        if (vaultt.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            files = vaultt.listFiles();
            Log.e("vault location", vaultt.getAbsolutePath());
            for (File single : files) {
                if (single.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".jpg") || single.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".JPG") ||
                        single.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".png") || single.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".PNG") ||
                        single.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".jpeg") || single.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".JPEG")) {
                    myFiles.add(single.getPath());
                }
            }
    return myFiles;

}
```

Also dont forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 in yout manifest file`

Comment: but i want to scan(Media scanner) them so that they can appear in gallery automatically